# Does JRebel really improve programming proficiency?

Tags: java, jrebel

i used JRebel for few days...but using eclipse Kepler version i did not feel much difference in program execution and Project build, i followed same  procedure as they mentioned on their official website.  ***Does JRebel really improve programming efficiency*** ?

Comment: You really start seeing a difference in larger projects. I'm working on one that takes about 2-2.5 minutes to build and deploy; if I do that several times a day, it really makes a difference. (And it's _efficiency_, not _proficiency_)

Comment: thanks @ aryn.galadar

Answer (score 2):

I think this question might get closed as it is very generic but if it doesn't then I think JRebel does not speed up build time or execution but allows classes to be updated on the fly.  This can negate the need for server restarts in web development and it is here where JRebel will save time (the time it takes to restart and redeploy an application once a class file is changed.

There is a nice video here

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Hope this helps

Comment: JRebel speeds up build time as a side effect. One doesn't need to assemble the full artefact to update it on the running server. Instead, JRebel can update individual classes. This means that one could just use IDE to compile the changed classes. Hence, in many cases JRebel kind of speeds up the build :)